# event listener calling function from external module

Tags: module, coronasdk, addeventlistener

as the title states i have an event listener which calls a function from my rocket class

but i receive an error upon calling said function, code below.

ROCKETCLASS.LUA

```
module(..., package.seeall)

function rocket()

local rocket = {}
local rocket_mt = { __index = rocket }  -- metatable
local sprite
local rockettop, rocketbottom, speedX, speedY


function rocket.new()   -- constructor

local newRocket = {
sprite = "red-rocket.png"

}
return setmetatable( newRocket, rocket_mt )
end 

function rocket:draw(x,y,group)

local spritesheetdata = {
width = 30,
height = 55,
numFrames = 7,
sheetContentWidth = 210,
sheetContentHeight = 55,
}


local spritesheet = graphics.newImageSheet( "red_rocket.png", spritesheetdata )



local spritesequencedata = {

 { name = "idle", frames = {1}, 
   } ,

 { name = "afterburn",
   start = 2,
   count = 2,
   time = 500,
   loopCount = 0, -- optional default 0(infinite)
   loopDirection = "forward" -- optional (default)
   } ,
   {  name = "explode",
   start = 4,
   count = 4,
   time = 1200,
   loopCount = 1
     }
 }

   sprite = display.newSprite( spritesheet, spritesequencedata)
   rockettop = {-14.5, 5, 0, -25,14.5,5}
   rocketbottom = {-14.5,7,-14.5,6,14.5,6,14.5,7}


   physics.addBody(sprite, {shape = rockettop},{bounce = 0.5,friction = 0.6, shape =  rocketbottom} )
   sprite.angularDamping = 2
   sprite.x = x
   sprite.y = y
   sprite:setSequence("idle")
   sprite:play()
   group:insert (sprite)

   end

function rocket:thrust(event)

speedX = 0.0025 * (math.sin(sprite.rotation*(math.pi/180)))
speedY = -0.0025 * (math.cos(sprite.rotation*(math.pi/180)))
if(event.phase =="began") then

  sprite:applyLinearImpulse(speedX, speedY, sprite.x, sprite.y)

  return true
  end
  sprite:setSequence("afterburn")
  sprite:play()

end

   return rocket


 end
```

and CONTROLS.LUA

```
module(..., package.seeall)
rocket = require("rocketclass")



local controlthrust = display.newImage("thrust control.png")
controlthrust.y = display.contentWidth/1.6   
controlthrust.x = display.contentWidth/1.1


local controlleft = display.newImage("direction controls.png")
controlleft.y = display.contentWidth/1.6

local controlright = display.newImage("direction controls.png")
controlright.y = display.contentWidth/1.6
controlright.x = display.contentWidth/6
controlright.rotation = 180



controlthrust:addEventListener("touch",rocket:thrust)
```

ERROR RECEIVED FROM CONSOLE IS:

controls.lua:21: attempt to call method 'thrust' 
stack traceback:
C: in function 'error'
?: in function 'gotoScene'
...nts\corona projects\rocket lander - classes\menu.lu

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you are calling rocket.new().  I would think you would need to do something like this:

```
 rocketclass = require("rocketclass")

 rocket = rocketclass.new()
```

before you set up the touch handler for it.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i did this in level1.lua (not shown) i have however fixed the issue by recreating the rocket class and removing the deprecated method module(..., package.seeall)
i can now fully control my rocket and all three lua files are interacting, if you would like to see, just let me know